# BigDecimal hasNextBigDecimal behavior

Tags: java, bigdecimal

The following code does exactly what is expected:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("0");
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        try {
            number = new BigDecimal(input.next());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not a number.");
        }
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

- Correct: It fails if I type a string.
- Correct: It fails if I type 1,1.
- Correct: It succeeds if I type 1.
- Correct: It succeeds if I type 1.1

If I remove the try catch block and replace it with a while loop, as follows, it does not do what is expected:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        while (!input.hasNextBigDecimal()) {
            System.out.print("Not a number, try again: ");
            input.next();
        }
        BigDecimal number = input.nextBigDecimal();
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

- Correct: It fails if I type a string.
- Not correct: It fails if I type 1.1.
- Correct: It succeeds if I type 1.
- Not correct: It succeeds if I type 1,1

Here is the output when I run: java Test

```
C:\>java Test
Enter a number: 1,1
1.1
```

Why would it accept a comma, but print a period?

If I run the following code, it prints out: en_ZA

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

As you can see at the following link, the decimal separator for my locale is the period:

http://www.localeplanet.com/java/en-ZA/index.html

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Edit:

On further investigation, I found the following:
https://www.sadev.co.za/content/how-correctly-format-currency-south-africa

So the locale technically does use the comma. Mind blown :)

Comment: I can't reproduce

Comment: Sounds like a locale issue.

Comment: what happens when set locale to english by `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en","US"));` as the first line of your `main` method?

Comment: @MauricePerry What does't make sense is that the only thing that has changed is the introduction of hasNextBigDecimal(). How would that affect the locale?

Comment: @guleryuz That solves the problem! This doesn't make sense. Our locale uses the period as the decimal point, not a comma.

Comment: @DevStep I would have to read the code of the `Scanner` class to answer that, but I don't have the time to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner.hasNextBigDecimal()` uses default locale's grouping and decimal separator (it seems '.' for grouping and ',' for decimal in your locale) to validate if next token matches `decimalpattern`:

```
...
DecimalFormat df =
    (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);

// These must be literalized to avoid collision with regex
// metacharacters such as dot or parenthesis
groupSeparator =   "\\" + dfs.getGroupingSeparator();
decimalSeparator = "\\" + dfs.getDecimalSeparator();
...
```

this piece of code is from `Scanner` class and executed when initializing your `scanner` instance. then `groupSeparator` and `decimalSeparator` are used when call to `Scanner.hasNextBigDecimal()` for checking if the next token matches a decimal format.

---

`new BigDecimal(String)` uses directly '.' as the decimal separator.

---

So, if you want to use `Scanner.hasNextBigDecimal()` and '.' as decimal separator for user inputs then you should use `Scanner`s `useLocale(Locale)` method. Your code shold look like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
while (!input.hasNextBigDecimal()) {
    System.out.print("Not a number, try again: ");
    input.next();
}
BigDecimal number = input.nextBigDecimal();
System.out.println(number);
```

---

> the program accepts a comma as valid input, but then prints a period
>   as the decimal point.

Again in `Scanner`'s `nextBigDecimal()` method replaces all `groupSeparator`'s with `""` and `decimalSeparator` with `"."` before calling 'new BigDecimal(String)'. The piece of code from `Scanner` class is:

```
private String processFloatToken(String token) {
    String result = token.replaceAll(groupSeparator, "");
    if (!decimalSeparator.equals("\\."))
        result = result.replaceAll(decimalSeparator, ".");
```

This is why it is accepting `,` and printing `.`.

Comment: Please see my edits above. My default locale uses the period as the decimal point. Also, the program accepts a comma as valid input, but then prints a period as the decimal point.